# C# Razor Task<string> async not working

Tags: c#, razor, async-await

So unfortunately I'm dealing with a C# Razor Web-forms (NOT MVC) web application.

I was given a C# program with a class consisting of async functions that I need to make work on a cshtml page and I cannot figure out how...

The two functions below are from a C# class that worked well with a C# Forms application. (Notice that "TextBox1" is assigned the text).

My problem is that I need the string variable "xml" to be displayed on a cshtml page (preferably in a "textarea" element) and I cannot seem to call the showData() function to retrieve the value

Can anyone help?

```
 public static async void showData(string gID)
{
    string xml = "";
    try
    {
       xml = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(gID);
       //The original code set a TEXTBOX to the string value
       //I need to revise this code so that I can display it on a cshtml page
       TextBox1.Text = xml;

    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to the server");
    }       
}


public static async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(string gID)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    urlLink = "*** A custom Intranet URL ***";
    ....
    ....
    ** preparing a Token/Client response url **
    ....
    ....
    string result = await serviceClient.GetStringAsync(urlLink);
    return result;
}
```

I've tried to bypass the `void` function and access the `Task<string>` function, but I cannot convert a `Task<string>` to a `string` value.

Comment: This is a very broad question. How are you going to call the `showData` method? You can call it using AJAX, or from another action. You need to remove the 'TextBox1.Text` so it is reusable. You need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes...I clearly state multiple times that `TextBox1.Text` needs to be removed. The problem is that you cannot call a `void` method and retrieve a string. So no, with this code..I cannot just use AJAX.

Comment: I'm confused at what more details you need. I'm simply trying to retrieve the string `xml` from the two functions. Please fully read my post before telling me you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`async void` is difficult to work with](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) to begin with, and [even more so on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

> I've tried to bypass the void function and access the Task function

Or just change `async void showData` to `async Task showData` - just as long as you avoid `async void`, you'll get to the same place.

> but I cannot convert a Task to a string value.

You do this with `await`:

```
var xml = await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync(gID);
```

or:

```
await showData(gID);
```

Your calling function will need to be marked `async` and return `Task`/`Task<T>`. Yes, this does cause `async`/`await` to "grow" through your code base, and yes, this is both normal and necessary.